# What does "runtime: INTERPRETED" mean in neo4j cypher query profiling?

Tags: neo4j, profiling, cypher

If you run a cypher query with PROFILE keyword in browser, you get a graphical query plan and a summary line like

```
Cypher version: CYPHER 3.0, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 702 total db hits in 299 ms.
```

What does runtime: INTERPRETED in this summary line mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two Cypher runtimes: interpreted and compiled.

The interpreted runtime facilitates database operations implemented in Scala and acts as an interpreted language.

The compiled runtime produces runnable bytecode that serves as a static implementation of a given query plan.

So in the profile results (which you get as a result of starting a query with `PROFILE`) the output is telling you that your query was executed using the interpreted runtime and not the compiled runtime.

There's a bit more info in [this blog post announcing the compiled runtime](https://neo4j.com/blog/new-on-neo4j-the-neo4j-2-3-0-milestone-2-release-is-here/).

Comment: As I understand, compiled runtime is faster, but it is only implemented for very simple queries yet.